# Change auto-complete its target workflow state

Tags: azure-devops

I've noticed that our pull requests that are set as auto-complete will go to the 'Complete' workflow state. Is it possible to change this to 'Resolved'?

Some context;

We have the following board sates:
[image]

At the moment the story automatically ends up in the 'QA Deployed / Closed' column while it should end up in the 'Code Reviewed' column.

In our setup we have:
'QA Deployed / Closed': Closed
'Code Reviewed': Resolved

Kind regards,